# Use numpy setdiff1d keeping the order

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 2, 3, 1, 0])
c = np.setdiff1d(b, a)
print("c", c)
```

The result is `c [0, 4]` but the answer I want is `c [4 0]`.

How can I do that?

Comment: you want it to print without commas?

Comment: Its bit unclear what you want.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants the array returned by `.setdiff1d` to not be sorted  but to retain the ordering of elements as per `b`...

Comment: Jon Clements know what I am thinking about.

Comment: @JonClements good catch. Didn't notice the flipped digits :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Get the mask  of non-matches with `np.in1d` and simply boolean-index into `b` to retain the order of elements in it -

```
b[~np.in1d(b,a)]
```

Sample step-by-step run -

```
In [14]: a
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [15]: b
Out[15]: array([4, 2, 3, 1, 0])

In [16]: ~np.in1d(b,a)
Out[16]: array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [17]: b[~np.in1d(b,a)]
Out[17]: array([4, 0])
```

Comment: @JonClements For duplicates, we need to know which one to keep as we need to maintain order. So, for those cases, we need more inputs from OP. But good point.

Comment: I'm guessing by index of first position but OP needs to clarify if 1) there may be duplicates in `b` and 2) as you say which position to consider for it...

Comment: @Divakar This method is easy for me to understand. thanks.

Comment: @CYC if your `b` was `np.array([4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0])` - how many 4's would you expect in your output?

Comment: @JonClements Each number will only appear once in my case.

Comment: If your input for `b` only contains unique values than this is the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want `c` to 1) have the elements of `b` that are not in `a` and 2) for them to be in the same order as they were in `b` you can use a list comprehension:

```
c = np.array([el for el in b if el not in a])
```

setdiff1d treats the arrays as sets and thus: 1) does not respect the order of the elements, 2) any element present more than once is treated as if it was present only once. For example this code:

```
a = np.array([4])
b = np.array([2, 4, 2, 1, 1])
c = np.setdiff1d(b, a)
print(c)
```

Will yield

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: it is a good method too, this method can handle the more general case. @Eugene thanks.