# Calculate randomly integers within a range in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate 5000 random integers between a range 0-50000 for example. I do so using the following code in python:

```
np.random.seed(0)
ind = np.random.randint(TOTAL_SIZE, size=(5000,)) //TOTAL_SIZE = 50.000
```

How can I store the rest integers. I tried something like ~ind but did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "rest integers"? Just store the output of `randint` separately?

Comment: @AndrasDeak, he means the integers from range (0,5000) which are not included in `ind` array.

Comment: If you want to keep track of the rest: `np.delete(np.arange(TOTAL_SIZE),nums)` where `nums` is the output of `randint`.

Comment: Here's a duplicate if I understood the question correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46261671/use-numpy-setdiff1d-keeping-the-order

Comment: can a random number appear more than once? if not you could just do `np.random.shuffle(np.arange(50000))` and slice it to get either the first 5000 or the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list comprehension.`

```
rest = np.array([i for i in range(0,50000) if i not in ind])
```